# Return statement inside function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this issue accidentally:

```js
const a = function() {
  return 
  {
    name: "Vijay Kumar"
  }
}
console.log(a());
```

This code above is printing `undefined` in console. I searched through many similarly titled questions, but those are all talking about different problems.

Comment: ASI changes your code to `return;`. change it to `return {`, moving the bracket up.

Comment: Visual Stidio does autoformatting which sometimes does break the code